# minimum of $a x^2+ b y^2+ c z^2$ under the condition $a\ln(x)+b\ln(y)+c\ln(z)=0$ for positive numbers $x,y,z$

Tags: limits, inequality, logarithms, holder-inequality

$n>0$, $x,y,z>0$ are arbitrary real numbers.
By Hölder's inequality
$$\tag1
(a+b+c)^{1\over n+1}(a x^{n + 1} + b y^{n + 1} + c z^{n + 1})^{n\over n+1}\ge ax^n+by^n+cz^n$$
so

> Given $ax^n+by^n+cz^n=a+b+c$, the mininum of $a x^{n + 1} + b y^{n + 1} + c z^{n + 1}$ is $a+b+c$.

When $n\to0$, using $\lim\frac{x^n-1}{n\ln(x)}=1$, the condition$$ax^n+by^n+cz^n=a+b+c⇔a(x^n-1)+b(y^n-1)+c(z^n-1)=0$$is close to $a\ln(x)+b\ln(y)+c\ln(z)=0$.

From the above

> Given $a\ln(x)+b\ln(y)+c\ln(z)=0$, the mininum of $a x+ b y+ c z$ is $a+b+c$.

Is this true?

My attempt:
Dividing (1) by $a+b+c$, raising to a power of $\frac1n$
$$\tag2\left(a x^{n + 1} + b y^{n + 1} + c z^{n + 1}\over a+b+c\right)^{1\over n+1}\ge\left(\frac{ax^n+by^n+cz^n}{a+b+c}\right)^{1\over n}$$
The right-hand side equals
$$\left(1+\frac{a(x^n-1)+b(y^n-1)+c(z^n-1)}{a+b+c}\right)^{1\over n}$$
When $n\to0$, this is close to
$$\left(1+n\frac{a \ln (x)+b \ln (y)+c \ln (z)}{a+b+c}\right)^{\frac1n}$$
Using $\lim_{n\to0}(1+nx)^{\frac1n}=e^x$, this equals
$$\exp\left(\frac{a \ln (x)+b \ln (y)+c \ln (z)}{a+b+c}\right)$$
so $(2)$ becomes
$${a x + b y + c z\over a+b+c}\ge\exp\left(\frac{a \ln (x)+b \ln (y)+c \ln (z)}{a+b+c}\right)$$
This proves the claim.

---

Original question:

> given $a\ln(x)+b\ln(y)+c\ln(z)=0$, the mininum of $a x^2+ b y^2+ c z^2$ is $a+b+c$.

This can be proved using same method:
By Hölder's inequality
$$\left(a x^{n + 2} + b y^{n + 2} + c z^{n + 2}\right)^n(a+b+c)^2\ge\left(ax^n+by^n+cz^n\right)^{n+2}$$
so
$$\left(a x^{n + 2} + b y^{n + 2} + c z^{n + 2}\over a+b+c\right)^{1\over n+2}\ge\left(\frac{ax^n+by^n+cz^n}{a+b+c}\right)^{1\over n}$$
When $n→0$, using $\lim\frac{x^n-1}{n\ln(x)}=1$,
$$\left(a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2\over a+b+c\right)^{1\over2}\ge\exp\left(\frac{a \ln (x)+b \ln (y)+c \ln (z)}{a+b+c}\right)$$
This proves the claim.

Comment: What do you mean by close

Comment: I'm not sure if the step "when $n→1$, this is close to ..." is correct

Comment: I agree with @hbghlyj - for me this approximation is unclear (it might be just me though). Also, in the end, if $n\to 1$, then the exponent tends to $+\infty$, not $\frac{1}{n+1}$ as you suggested above.

Comment: @VeselinDimov I was wrong. It should be $n→0$. I modified the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fact 1.** Let $a, b, c \ge 0$ and $x, y, z > 0$ with $a\ln x + b\ln y + c\ln z = 0$. Then
$ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 \ge a + b + c$.

**Proof of Fact 1.**

Using the known inequality $\ln u \le u - 1$ for all $u > 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 &\ge a(\ln(x^2) + 1)
 + b(\ln(y^2) + 1) + c(\ln(z^2) + 1)\\
 &= 2(a\ln x + b\ln y + c\ln z) + (a + b + c)\\
 &= a + b + c.
\end{align*}

We are done.